# Minio bucket size

Tags: java, minio

I want to calculate bucket size of minio.
is it possible to calculate storage quota using MinioClient?
 or is there any best way to calculate bucket size of minio storage.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Yes we can.

**first**
Downlaod the client e.g. https://dl.min.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc or any other OS you have

**second**
set the proper configuration which you need:

- end-point e.g. `https://s3-buket.example.com`
- access-key  e.g. `jgDbxCy9Uv35sQ7H`
- secret-key  e.g. `EQqSA5OZLVYqZSztbgq28Seezn9pkX4V`

and set it:

```
minmc alias set s3p https://s3-buket.example.com 'jgDbxCy9Uv35sQ7H' 'EQqSA5OZLVYqZSztbgq28Seezn9pkX4V'
```

- `minmc` MinIO client
- `alias set` options
- `s3p` a name

after running it we will see:

```
Added `s3p` successfully.
```

**third**
then you can run / use `mc` sub-command e.g. `ls` , `du` , etc

here is a screenshot

[image]

---

[source](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```sh
mc ls -r --json your_bucket_path | awk '{ FS=","; print $4 }' | awk '{ FS=":"; n+=$2 } END{ print n }'
```

Comment: Or using jq instead of awk: `mc ls -r --json your_bucket_path | jq -s 'map(.size) | add'`

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @mikijov, but using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead of awk:

```
mc ls -r --json your_bucket_path | jq -s 'map(.size) | add'
```

Answer (score 2):

Show human-readable size:

```
mc ls -r --json your_bucket_path | jq -s 'map(.size) | add' | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7
```

Answer (score 1):

The minio client `mc` as of version [2019-08-14T20-49-49Z](https://github.com/minio/mc/releases/tag/RELEASE.2019-08-14T20-49-49Z) has a `du` subcommand that can be used as follows to determine the size of a bucket:

```
mc du --depth 1 <alias>/your_bucket_path
```

where `<alias>` is a configuration for an S3 endpoint in accordance with the [mc documentation](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc.html).